# Windows software to turn a 3gp video on its side before upload?

Tags: video-editor

My camera phone takes video in 3gp format. I've inadvertently taken a video sideways and want to turn it 90 degrees for upload to services such as YouTube and Facebook.

What software package can I use on Windows to do this, or is there another option?  <strike>I've looked at the YouTube upload interface and it doesn't have an option to turn the video.</strike>

Comment: After a bit of research I'm considering ffmpeg transpose http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#transpose but have to sit down with it to learn a bit more.

Comment: YouTube note: In fact, at this point in time, YouTube does allow a video to be turned on its side after it has been uploaded. The video is then reprocessed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Windows Live Movie Maker](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/products/features/movie-maker), which is free with Windows Live Essentials.  [Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlqqlS8CDv4) is a tutorial on how to do it.

It looks like Windows Movie Maker doesn't have native support for the 3GP format, but you should be able to download a CODEC for it.

For Mac users, [iMovie](http://www.apple.com/ilife/imovie/) is the equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The following will flip a video 90 degrees clockwise:

```
ffmpeg -i input.3gp -filter:v 'transpose=1' -c:a copy \
-c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset veryfast output.mp4
```

To flip it 90 degrees anti-clockwise, use 'transpose=2'. See [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose) for more information. Note that this will require a fairly up-to-date version of ffmpeg.